# Is there any proverb or idiom in English that says that "If you understand yourself and your opponent, you can win any battles"?

Tags: idiom-requests, proverbs

There is a Chinese proverb saying that "*If you understand yourself and your enemy, you can win any battles*"?

It seems that the proverb was from "*The Art of War*" of Sun Tzu

> “If you know the enemy and know yourself, you need not fear the result
>   of a hundred battles. If you know yourself but not the enemy, for
>   every victory gained you will also suffer a defeat. If you know
>   neither the enemy nor yourself, you will succumb in every battle.” ([Source](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/17976-if-you-know-the-enemy-and-know-yourself-you-need))

My question is that, is there any proverb in English that expresses the similar meaning

Maybe "*He who sees through life and death will meet with most success*". but seem this expression just focus on yourself and does not say that you need to understand the enemy.

So,
Is there any proverb or idiom in English that says that "*If you understand yourself and your opponent, you can win any battles*"?

Comment: This article might tbe of interest. "*Sun Tzu Didn’t Invent “Know Yourself, Know Your Enemy*” ---> http://learnoutlive.com/sun-tzu-didnt-invent-know-yourself-know-your-enemy/

Answer (score 5):

I think the famous Chinese saying is usually expressed in  English  as  ***'[Know your Enemy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Know_Your_Enemy)***':

> - a [saying](https://books.google.it/books?id=DX_oAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA309&lpg=PA309&dq=know%20your%20enemy%20idiom&source=bl&ots=p4qB5objFs&sig=0dVp6vwA2jfr_Os9i7IXJb9y3mQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBmoVChMIyaLh2_-2xwIVAX4aCh3iPQM0#v=onepage&q=know%20your%20enemy%20idiom&f=false) derived from Sun Tzu's The Art of War

(Wikipedia) and (TPS Frequency Dictionary of Mandarin Chinese: A Study Guide)

Comment: Also: *know thyself, know thy enemy*...

Comment: But it does not express that "you should know yourself". Not many people know themselves

Comment: Except that the English expression doesn't claim to guarantee success.

Comment: @user105551 - yes, there is also the more complete version  as suggested by jxh, but for some reason that is the expression that is more popular in western countries that refers to the Chinese saying.

Answer (score 2):

A common English expression is: "Keep your friends close and your enemies closer"

This is often attributed to Sun Tzu and I always thought it was from Hamlet's Polonius but its actually from the Godfather Part II: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sun_Tzu

Comment: Here it cites it as a quote from Sun-tzu: http://www.quotationspage.com/quotes/Sun-tzu/